# How to get the geometry of all tables in a postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, sql, query

[image: **My First query used to return all tables name :**]

[image: **The second one is to return the type of ONE table:**]

How can I return all tables geom?

Comment: check the view public.geometry_columns

Answer (score 1):

There are two views that you need to check `geometry_columns` and `geography_columns` that will provide you with a list like:

```
"ian";"public";"coastline";"geom";2;27700;"MULTILINESTRING"
"ian";"public";"motorway";"geom";2;27700;"MULTILINESTRING"
```